# Require Ivy Support for @circlon/angular-tree-component package

Tags: angular

Currently @circlon/angular-tree-component package is updated till version 11.0.4 but there is issue with IVY support. We are using this package from few years and currently after migration of project to angular 15 we found that ther is no Ivy support and from last three years there is no update on the package. Is there any plan to update this package to latest angular version and Ivy support or in future this package going to be deprecated. In case there will be updates then when can we expect next release?

Expectation is to have upgrade and latest Ivy Support on the package.

Answer (score 1):

This lib doesn't seem to be supported anymore.

Per [this discussion](https://github.com/CirclonGroup/angular-tree-component/issues/956) on the repo, there is a community fork that addresses the issue of Ivy support : https://github.com/ali-hm/angular-tree-component.

You can install it from `@ali-hm/angular-tree-component`